# Automate BTWiFi login using a FON account

Tags: wireless-networking, script, hotspot, auto-login

I'm a user of British Telecom's Wifi hotspot. The service is good, but after some time of inactivity it logs me off and asks for user name and password.

It's really annoying in the long run.

Did anybody already reverse-engineer the login system and produced a Python/Bash/Perl script?

Or is there a generic way to do these kind of things?

Comment: Android? Are you using the BT Wi-fi app?

Comment: I don't own any android, I have a raspberry pi though!

Answer (score 2):

Save this as a scrip and have it run every 10 mins. Dont forget to add your username and password at the top!

```
#!/bin/bash

# CONF

DBG=true
RELOG_UNAME=usernamehere
RELOG_PASSW=passwordhere

# END CONF

IS_LOGGED_IN=$(wget "https://www.btopenzone.com:8443/home" --timeout 30 -O - 2>/dev/null | grep "accountLogoff")

if [ "$IS_LOGGED_IN" ]

then
  [[ $DBG ]] && echo "currently logged in. Nothing to do.."

else
  [[ $DBG ]] && echo "It's not logged in.. Will log in!"
  OUT=$(wget -qO- --post-data "USERNAME=$RELOG_UNAME&PASSWORD=$RELOG_PASSW" "https://btwifi.portal.fon.com/remote?res=hsp-login&HSPNAME=FonBT%3AGB&WISPURL=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.btopenzone.com%3A8443%2FfonLogon&WISPURLHOME=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.btopenzone.com%3A8443&VNPNAME=FonBT%3AGB&LOCATIONNAME=FonBT%3AGB")
  ONLINE=$(echo $OUT | grep youre_online )
  if [ "$ONLINE" ]
  then
    [[ $DBG ]] && echo "You're online!"
  else
    [[ $DBG ]] && echo "Could not login :("
  fi
fi
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, but an explanation would be nice :-)

Comment: Sorry i was in a rush so it was a bit of a brain dump, have that run every 10mins or so and it will keep you logged in. Just replace the username and password. Part of the script was credit to someone else. But cant remember where from now

Comment: Well, this is awkward. You did not write the code you pasted, and I'm certain because I wrote it myself one year ago, a few days after posting my question.

https://gist.github.com/sscarduzio/05ed0b41d6234530d724

Comment: @sscarduzio any chance to have an equivalent script working with the Vodafone free wifi (Fon)? I am looking at it right now but I have no clue on how to get the http commands.

Comment: You can do it yourself, I used chrome "inspect element" -> select network tab, look at the HTTP requests, right click and copy curl command. Then I adapted curl to wget because I didn't have curl installed in my embedded device.

Comment: Meh. I am getting mad with it. I have curl, lynx and I just can't make it working. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @sscarduzio I've found the solution for Vodafone. The problem was that at each new connection it issues a challenge number, which is never the same. If you (or anyone else) are interested you can find it in here:
http://superuser.com/questions/1053990/automatic-login-to-vodafone-community-wifi-fon-via-unix-script/1062530#1062530
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Really nice exercise. Logging in with Vodafone must be really annoying if you went all the way to circumvent the challenge parameter, kill the captive network detector etc :)

Comment: yeah, that's what has been the pain indeed. But after few runs with Chrome as you suggested it became clearer what was going on with the challenge number. Then the captive network assistant blocking the DNS queries just added damage to injury. No wonder I was stuck. But today I took my time and it eventually came out! Although I must say that having a script killing that annoying splash window just feels gooood. >:)