# Automatic login to Vodafone Community WiFi (Fon) via Unix script

Tags: wireless-networking, login, web, curl, lynx

First I have to say that my question is similar to [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/802448/automate-btwifi-login-using-a-fon-account)

I am using a Vodafone Community Fon AP and it often disconnects. In OS X, which I'm using, there is a tool called Captive Network Assistant to connect to these APs. It does the job but unfortunately it doesn't keep the username/password (I've opened a bug report with Apple), so each time I have to type them again.

I have curl, lynx, wget installed but I'm a noob with those tools. And I can get whatever is needed via Macport. With Google Chrome I identified few URLs for the login but none worked. At least I couldn't make them working. Here some samples:

**This is the starting URL:**

https://it.portal.vodafone-wifi.com/jcp/it?res=welcome&nasid=90-55-6E-E5-E0-60&uamip=192.168.6.1&uamport=80&mac=00-19-E3-33-E0-72&challenge=bd551b56b4a5......26061f111ceaf&ip=192.168.6.2&userurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com&lang=it&LANGUAGE=it

**This the URL which should actually do the login:**

http://192.168.6.1/logon?username=FON%2FVF_IT%2F<**USER**>%40<**DOMAIN**>&password=**6223980fe........93ea753ef4de**'

Where USER is the username, DOMAIN the email address domain. I've changed some numbers with dots in the password field for security reasons, that could be an encryption of the password I use.

I tried passing the credentials with wget/curl/lynx but I always get a return URL with a "BAD PASSWORD" in the link.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've eventually found the solution. It may take a couple of loops to connect, but at end end it authenticates. It works on OS X El Capitan 10.11.4, any adjustment for previous OS X versions (if needed) or Linux should be easy.

Beware that it needs to have "wget" installed and in the $PATH.

To launch the script as an OS X user agent at login [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22872222/4243998). Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/sh

######################################################################
#
# OS X Script to automatically reconnect to a Vodafone Community AP
# when the connection drops.
#
# It's designed to support to be launched as an OS X login agent
# logging to the console.
# 
# Tested only on OS X EL Capitan. It should also run on Linux without
# many modifications
#
# Version 3.0
# Author: Michele Dall'Agata
#
# CHANGELOG:
#
# v3.0: All connection parameters are automatically retrieved from the 
#       Vodafone Station.
#       Force the use of Vodafone-WiFi APs.
#       Cleaner log.
# v2.2: Check after restarting the WiFi if the connection is up and continue
#       in case. It happens quite often.
# v2.1: All references to the WiFi interface now correctly use $WIFI_IF.
# v2.0: Reorganized the logic.
#       Added section OS X specific.
#       Loop waiting for WiFi connecting after restarting.
#       Added $WIFI_IF variable for WiFi interface.
#       Check if it is a Vodafone Community AP.
#       Fixed all wget commands.
#       Complete although stripped logging. Now it's clearer which step
#       is executed.
# v1.1: Restarts the WiFi interface.
# v1.0: first working skeleton. Hey, it did the job! :)
#
######################################################################


# $PATH should include the location where wget is installed
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/local/bin

# The Vodafone Country code. This is the code for Italy
COUNTRY=VF_IT

# The URL uses "%40" for "@". We do the same
USERNAME=<Your username>%40<Your domain>
PASSWORD=<Your Password>

# This will be visible in the Console app
# Set it to /dev/null if you don't want any log
LOGFILE=~/Library/Logs/Vodafone.log

# WiFi network interface. Option+Click on WiFI icon to get the one on
# your Mac. Change it accordingly.
WIFI_IF=en0

######################################################################
# For reference only. They get automatically set by the script
#

# MAC address of the Vodafone Station. 
NASID=
# MAC address of your WiFi interface. 
MACADDR=
# Vodafone Station (gateway) IP address.
IPADDR=


#######################################################################
# Begin Script
#######################################################################

# Log beginning of execution
echo >> $LOGFILE
echo $(date "+%d %b %H:%M:%S") Starting Vodafone Connection agent >> $LOGFILE

while [ true ]
do

# If the WiFi is switched off do nothing.  Otherwise check if we are connected to
# a captive network

    ! ifconfig $WIFI_IF | grep  "RUNNING" || \
        wget -qO- http://captive.apple.com/hotspot-detect.html 2>&1 | \
        grep 'Success' >> /dev/null

    if [ $?  != 0 ]; then

        echo $(date "+%d %b %H:%M:%S") >> $LOGFILE
        echo $(date "+%d %b %H:%M:%S") Connection is down. Reauthenticating >> $LOGFILE

# This is OS X specific
        if [ $(uname) == "Darwin" ]; then

# Turn WiFi off and on in case the connection has got stuck (exclamation mark on WiFi icon)
            echo $(date "+%d %b %H:%M:%S") Switching WiFi Off >> $LOGFILE
            networksetup -setairportpower $WIFI_IF off

            echo $(date "+%d %b %H:%M:%S") Switching WiFi On >> $LOGFILE
            networksetup -setairportpower $WIFI_IF on

# We are here to reconnect to a Vodafone Community netwok.      
            networksetup -setairportnetwork $WIFI_IF Vodafone-WiFi

# Wait for the WiFi to connect to the router and get an IP address
            while ! ifconfig $WIFI_IF | grep  "inet " 2>&1 > /dev/null ; do
                echo $(date "+%d %b %H:%M:%S") Waiting for WiFi to connect >> $LOGFILE
                networksetup -setairportnetwork $WIFI_IF Vodafone-WiFi
                sleep 1
            done
            sleep 2

The connection may be up already. Check and in case loop again
            wget -qO- http://captive.apple.com/hotspot-detect.html 2>&1 | grep 'Success' > /dev/null && \
                echo $(date "+%d %b %H:%M:%S") The connection is up and running\! >> $LOGFILE && \
                continue

# This could be at the beginning of the loop but the connection was down 
# so restarting the WiFi interface may help anyway.

# TODO: To check what happens if we use a different a different network
            if [ $(networksetup -getairportnetwork $WIFI_IF | awk '{print $NF}') != "Vodafone-WiFi" ];
            then
                echo $(date "+%d %b %H:%M:%S") Not a Vodafone AP
                sleep 60
                continue
            fi

        fi
#
# if Captive Network Assistant app launches for some reason DNS doesn't work.
# Just kill it

        pgrep "Captive Network Assistant" && echo $(date "+%d %b %H:%M:%S") Killed Captive Network Assistant.. \
            $(killall -9 "Captive Network Assistant" 2>&1) >> $LOGFILE

# We can get all needed parameters from the returned URL.
# Grab them querying any IP number and store them in $IPPARM

        IPPARM=$(wget -qO- --timeout=10 -t 1 8.8.8.8 2>&1 | grep loginVodafone | grep -i challenge | \
            sed -e 's/\&/=/g' | awk -F= '{ print $7 " " $9 " " $13 " " $15}')

# Assign each value
        read NASID IPADDR MACADDR CHALLENGE <<< $IPPARM

# If empty either the Captive Network Assistant deamon restored the connection or something went wrong. 
# Loop again

        if [ -z $CHALLENGE ]; then
            echo $(date "+%d %b %H:%M:%S") The station returned no login URL. The connection may be up. \
                >> $LOGFILE
        else

# Kill it again...
            pgrep "Captive Network Assistant" && echo $(date "+%d %b %H:%M:%S") Killed Captive Network Assistant.. \
                $(killall -9 "Captive Network Assistant" 2>&1) >> $LOGFILE
            echo $(date "+%d %b %H:%M:%S") Connecting to AP $IPADDR with BSSID $NASID >> $LOGFILE

            wget -qO-  --timeout=10 --keep-session-cookies \
                --post-data "chooseCountry=$COUNTRY%2F&userFake=$USERNAME$&UserName=$COUNTRY%2F$USERNAME&Password=$PASSWORD&_rememberMe=on" \
                "https://it.portal.vodafone-wifi.com/jcp/it?res=login&nasid=$NASID&uamip=$IPADDR&uamport=80&mac=$MACADDR&challenge=$CHALLENGE" \
                2>&1 >> /dev/null
        fi

# It may need some time to fully establish the connection?
        sleep 3

# And kill it again...
        pgrep "Captive Network Assistant" && echo $(date "+%d %b %H:%M:%S") Killed Captive Network Assistant.. \
            $(killall -9 "Captive Network Assistant" 2>&1) >> $LOGFILE

# Log if the connection was re-established
        (wget -qO- http://captive.apple.com/hotspot-detect.html 2>&1 | grep 'Success' > /dev/null && \
            echo $(date "+%d %b %H:%M:%S") The connection is up and running\! >> $LOGFILE) || \
            echo $(date "+%d %b %H:%M:%S") The connection is still down. Retrying >> $LOGFILE

    else

# No need for more than 1s. When the connection is up it's just 1 HTTP query per loop.
        sleep 1
    fi
done
```